# Are elements with static position always behind the other elements?

Tags: html, css

```
<style type="text/css">
    p.example {
        position: relative;
        top: 25px;
        background-color: red;
        }
</style>

<p class="example">First paragraph</p>
<p>Second paragraph</p>
```

When I load this code in a browser the first paragraph appears on top of the second, which is weird because I expect the second paragraph to render after the first one. Even if I use z-index, the second paragraph is still in back. Are static positioned elements always in back?

Comment: As you know by default position have a `static` value and for second `p` element no any property will apply. so `z-index` will apply for first `p` as you described in CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Positioned elements (and their children) are always displayed in front of any non-positioned elements. (To say an element is "positioned" means that it has a position value other than static, e.g., relative, absolute, etc.)

z-index has no effect on elements that are not positioned, which is why it appeared ineffective for you. This is a standard behavior of HTML (it follows [W3C specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/zindex.html)).

To better understand this behavior, I suggest you read this article which explains things in greater detail: http://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/

Answer (score 2):

Z-index should work...

```
p.example {
    position: relative;
    top: 25px;
    background-color: red;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

See the jsfiddle below.

http://jsfiddle.net/qddoyvbo/

Comment: Thanks, but When I set the z-index of first paragraph to 1 and the the second paragraph to 10, the second p is still in back. So why is it like this? I'm not so concerned about what works, I want to understand it.

Answer (score 1):

```
<style type="text/css">
div#ex{
    position: relative;
    top: 25px;
}
p.example {
    background-color: red;
}
</style>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="ex">
   <p class="example">First paragraph</p>
   <p>Second paragraph</p>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yy4Ldwc5/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get second `<p>` up you have to use `position:relative` and `z-index`, as you already applied `position:relative` for first `<p>`, it comes up

Answer (score 0):

try this

```css
p.example {
  position: relative;
  top: 25px;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<p class="example">First paragraph</p>
<p>Second paragraph</p>
```